# How fast are transfers from Amazon EC2 to Amazon Glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am using a large, 1st generation instance on Amazon EC2 in the `us-east-1` region, and would like to transfer data to Amazon Glacier. I will be transferring data from the instance's ephemeral storage. What are the data transfer rates I can expect?

Comment: Different instance types have different network performance.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yeah, that's why I specified my instance type, and that I was using ephemeral storage (vs. EBS)

Answer (score 1):

Using Boto's `bin/glacier` utility to post data to Glacier, I achieved rates anywhere from 4–5MB/s for files sized in the hundreds of megabytes. I also transferred a 213.25 GB (228,977,335,290 bytes) file in 33,689 seconds, which is 6.48 MB/s.

Comment: Was this on an m1.large? Different instances have different network speeds.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yep, an m1.large

Comment: OK. I see faster transfers to Glacier (20 MB/s) from my m1.small. It probably varies based on the network usage of other VMs on the host.